# How can I allow visitors to embed audio files hosted on my server on their websites?

Tags: javascript

I've seen text boxes on websites where you can copy a script and paste it onto a webpage and it will embed an audio player into a remote website. I have some songs hosted on my server and would like other people to play them remotely from an audio player they can embed into their website. Where can I learn how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For greatest compatibility for the time being, you'll need to embed some Flash.

But keep in mind the `audio` element.